# Array [1,2,3....n]. A number is missing in that series. What is the optimum way to find out that number?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There will be an array starting from 1,2,3.... n. If any one number is removed from the array what is the optimun way to find out removed number.

Comment: So you are given an array with n-1 length or one number is duplicate here?

Comment: Try geeksforgeeks solution https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-missing-number/

Comment: yes..think of it like a [1,2,3,4,6,7]. 5 is missing. What is the optimum way to find out the missing 5.

Comment: If the array is sorted, you just iterate through the array until you find two elements that are adjacent, but not consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

The following is just one possible way to find the missing one.

If `n` is given, then the sum of the series `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` is,

```
S =  1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n
  = n * (n + 1) / 2
```

So, ultimately, you know the value of `S`. Now sum up all the integers you are given. Let's call it `S'`. And the difference between `S` and `S'`, `(S - S')` is the answer.

This will work even the given integers are in random order. This will not require a `binary search` where it is required that the integers must be sorted and needs an extra `nlogn` time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers are in serial order

**Two solutions**

1. Check while reading.
2. Binary search for the missing number.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is sorted then the element can be found in `O(log n) time`  and `O(1) space`

Using Binary Search.

```cpp
int search(int *ar, int n) { 
    int a = 0, b = n - 1; 
    int mid; 
    while ((b - a) > 1) { 
        mid = a + ((b-a) >> 1); 
        if ((ar[a] - a) != (ar[mid] - mid)) 
            b = mid; 
        else if ((ar[b] - b) != (ar[mid] - mid)) 
            a = mid; 
    } 
    return (ar[mid] + 1); 
}
```

If the array is not sorted

```cpp
n*(n+1)/2 - sum(array)

where n is the length of the array.
```